# How to ignore spins is Qiskit chemistry package?

Tags: qiskit, programming

Is it possible to use built-in `qiskit.chemistry` tools, such as `VQE`, `UCCSD`, etc., without using the notion of spins ('alpha'/'beta')?

Let's say, I want to decsribe a system having 5 fermionic modes in the second-quantized formalism. I want to start from a state in which 3 of them are occupied. I can provide a second-quantized Hamiltonian written in terms of $h_1$ and $h_2$ coefficients and ladder operators.

How do I do all that?